# Software version

Tags: windows, versioning, software-distribution

imagine a sofware is released with version `1.8`

Is it possible to release new version like this :

```
1.9
1.10
1.11
```

or is it disordered ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you are talking about. In a file system the folder /MyApp1.9 will come after /MyApp1.10, but must autoupdating software will know the difference and order it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it's a matter of taste, so the short answer would be yes you could if you want to. Think about windows for instance, 3.1 followed by 95, 98, 2000, Vista, 7 and now 8. Some major players do it, as could you if you like.